# Multi-dimensional arrays: Ignoring spaces in the input

Tags: c, arrays, multidimensional-array

I'm new to c programming and I have a school work wherein the user inputs a puzzle 7x7 (using multidimensional arrays). My problem is I don't know how to remove spaces from the input, because there should be a space after every character. for example:

```
1 2 1 1 1 1 1
2 2 1 1 1 2 1
1 2 1 1 1 1 1
2 2 1 1 1 2 1
1 2 1 1 1 1 1
2 2 1 1 1 2 1
1 2 1 1 1 1 1
```

I need to disregard the spaces and still have 7 characters per row. 
Thanks! :)
Here is my code but it's not running.

```
int main(){
char puzzle[7][7];
char input[7][7];
int i;
int j;  
int a;
int b;
for(i=0; i<7; i++){
for(j=0; j<7; j++){
    fgets(input[i][j],sizeof(input[i][j]), stdin);
        for(i=0, j=0; i,j<strlen(input[i][j]); i++,j++){
            if(input[i][j]==' ')
                continue;
                puzzle[a][b]=input[i][j];
                a++;
                b++;
            }
        }
    }
getch();
}
```

Comment: Could you please show something, like how you currently are getting input, and so on? The relevant extract of the code could help...

Comment: `scanf("%d", &array[r][c]);`

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because the poster has not demonstrated any effort in writing code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
int a[7][7];
for (int i = 0; i < 7 ; i++)
    for (int j = 0; j < 7 ; j++)
        scanf("%i",&a[i][j]);
```

`scanf("%i",&a[i][j]);` will ignore spaces and new-line symbols.

Comment: .. should also check the return value from `scanf` - but I guess that is an exercise for the poster